# An easy way to replace fread()'s with reading from a byte array?

Tags: c, arrays, fread

I have a piece of code that needs to be run from a restricted environment that doesn't allow stdio (Flash's Alchemy compiler).  The code uses standard fopen/fread functions and I need to convert it to read from a char* array.  Any ideas on how to best approach this?  Does a wrapper exist or some library that would help?

Thanks!

EDIT: I should also mention that it's reading in structs. Like this:

```
fread(&myStruct, 1, sizeof(myStruct), f);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know of any such wrapper, but I don't think it would be too difficult to make your own.  That's because C's approach to file I/O hides everything behind the `FILE*` interface, which actually makes it **nicely object-oriented**.

Since you're using C rather than C++, I would suggest using preprocessor macros to replace every instance of `fopen()`, `fclose()` and `fread()` with `MEM_fopen()` etc. which are routines that you will define.  You will need to define your own `FILE` type, for which you could simply use the following:

```
typedef unsigned char *FILE;
```

(If you need to manage EOF, you will instead need `FILE` to be a `struct` with an additional `length` field.)

Then your `MEM_fread()` function will look something like:

```
int MEM_fread(unsigned char *buf, size_t size, size_t n, FILE *f) {
    memcpy(buf, *f, size * n);
    *f += size * n;
    return n;
}
```

The signature for the `MEM_fopen()` "constructor" may need to change slightly, since the identifier you need is now a memory address instead of a filename.

Answer (score 2):

glibc has `fmemstream`, `open_memstream`, and `open_wmemstream` which all return a FILE * that you can use with the stdio file IO functions directly and also call fclose on.

```
man 3 fmemopen
```

Answer (score 1):

Is `memcpy` insufficient?  It should be pretty easy to write a wrapper around it that has a signature similar to `fread`.

Answer (score 1):

Just write your own version of fread().  Pass the .obj or .lib to the linker *before* the CRT library and the linker will pick your definition instead of the one from the CRT library.